# NSNumbers stored in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to store numbers in a NSMutableArray, but when I check it, all I get is garbage.

```
-(void)storeIntoArray:(int)indexInt
{
    NSNumber *indexNum = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:indexInt];
    [last100 insertObject:indexNum atIndex:prevCount];
    prevCount++;

    if(prevCount > 100)
    {
        prevCount = 0;
        cycledOnce = YES;
    }

}

-(BOOL)checkArray:(int)indexInt
{
for(int i = 0;i < [last100 count];i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Stored: %d",[last100 objectAtIndex:i]);
        if (indexInt == (int)[last100 objectAtIndex:i]) {
            NSLog(@"Same entry, trying again");
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

When I check, I'll get values back like `Stored: 110577680` and just various garbage values.

Comment: Not that it's your issue, but you're leaking every number you're storing.

Comment: Good catch. Release indexNum?

Comment: Note that it would likely be more efficient to use an NSMutableSet to detect duplicate entries (if that is your intention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the NSNumber object address, not its value.  Try using `intValue`.  Or, if you want to print the object directly, use `%@` rather than `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Stored: %d",[last100 objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Should be:
    NSLog(@"Stored: %@",[last100 objectAtIndex:i]);

NSNumber is an object not an integer.

Comment: More to the point, it should be `if (indexInt == [[last100 objectAtIndex:i] intValue])`.